# How to keep webpage same layout throughout all screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I know this technology is OLD, but I never understood how it was done.
Back in the days, before websites were responsive. Pages would just shrink all the way down and look like the full desktop display on mobile devices. Just smaller.

How do you do that? I want my website to just shrink down. But be the same throughout all media sizes.

Comment: Websites are only responsive if you make them responsive (which you definitely should)

Answer (score 1):

> How do you do that?

You do nothing.

That's how devices with small physical displays behave when given a webpage that doesn't explicitly state it has support for small viewports by opting-in with [meta viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one to view the same webpage allover screens.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=YOURCONTAINERWIDTH">
```

Eg:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
```